# Building OpenFOAM-v1812 - configure error for ParaView

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, build, configure

Can anyone help with an error on building [`OpenFOAM`](https://openfoam.com/download/install-source.php), a computational fluid dynamics package? This was on configuring the dependency [`ParaView`](https://openfoam.com/code/build-guide.php) with: `./makeParaView`

```
~/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812$ ./makeParaView 
Using qmake=/usr/bin/qmake

ParaView_SOURCE_DIR=/home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/ParaView-v5.6.0
ParaView_BUILD_DIR=/home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0
ParaView_DIR=/home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0

Build stages selected
---------------------
    -patch    true
    -config   true
    -make     true
    -install  true
---------------------
Features selected
    mesa      false
    mpi       false
    python    false
    qt        true
---------------------
Version information
    paraview  5.6.0
    major     5.6
    build     Release
    qt        4.8.7
---------------------
no patch found for paraview-5.6.0
Using cmake=/usr/bin/cmake
----
Configuring paraview-5.6.0 (major version: 5.6)
    MPI    support : false
    Python support : false
    MESA   support : false
    GL2  rendering : true
    QT dev support : true
    Source         : /home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/ParaView-v5.6.0
    Build          : /home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0
    Target         : /home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0
    cmake          : /usr/bin/cmake
    Build suffix   : none
----

/usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DPARAVIEW_INSTALL_DEVELOPMENT_FILES=ON -DVTK_RENDERING_BACKEND=OpenGL2 -DPARAVIEW_BUILD_QT_GUI=ON -DPARAVIEW_QT_VERSION=4 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/ParaView-v5.6.0

----

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.7.4") 
-- Could not use git to determine source version, using version 5.6.0
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler - /usr/bin/f95
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 5.5.0
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/f95
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/f95  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/f95 supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/f95 supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- Performing Test VTK_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS_ALLOWED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_ERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_ERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Performing Test VTK_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS_ALLOWED - Success
-- Performing Test Support for 64 bit file systems
-- Performing Test Support for 64 bit file systems - Success
-- Group StandAlone modules: vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonCore;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkCommonMisc;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkInfovisCore;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersVerdict;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkFiltersSources;vtkFiltersCore;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkFiltersPoints;vtkFiltersTopology;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkParallelCore;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOImage;vtkIOAMR;vtkIOMovie;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOImport;vtkIOSegY;vtkIOExodus;vtkIOInfovis;vtkIOXMLParser;vtkIOGeometry;vtkIOLegacy;vtkIOParallel;vtkIOParallelXML;vtkIOTecplotTable;vtkIOPLY;vtkIOMINC;vtkIOXML;vtkIOCore;vtkIOSQL;vtkIOAsynchronous;vtkIONetCDF;vtkIOVideo;vtkIOEnSight;vtkIOVeraOut;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkImagingColor;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkImagingCore;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkImagingStencil;vtkChartsCore
-- Group Rendering modules: vtkGeovisCore;vtkInteractionImage;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkIOExportPDF;vtkIOExport;vtkRenderingImage;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkRenderingFreeType;vtkRenderingCore;vtkViewsInfovis;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsCore
-- Group Qt modules: vtkGUISupportQtSQL;vtkGUISupportQt;vtkRenderingQt;vtkViewsQt;vtkPVVTKExtensionsRendering;pqWidgets
-- Group MPI modules: vtkFiltersParallelMPI;vtkFiltersParallelDIY2;vtkFiltersParallelVerdict;vtkFiltersParallelGeometry;vtkParallelMPI;vtkdiy2;vtkDomainsParallelChemistry;vtkIOParallelNetCDF;vtkIOMPIParallel;vtkIOMPIImage
-- Group Imaging modules: vtkFiltersImaging;vtkInteractionImage;vtkRenderingImage;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkImagingColor;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkImagingStencil
-- Group Web modules: vtkWebPython;vtkWebCore;vtkWebGLExporter
-- Group Tk modules: vtkRenderingTk
-- Group Views modules: vtkViewsGeovis;vtkViewsContext2D
-- Group ParaViewCore modules: smTestDriver;vtkPVCommon;vtkPVClientServerCoreCore;vtkPVServerManagerCore;vtkPVVTKExtensionsCore;vtkPVServerImplementationCore
-- Group ParaViewRendering modules: vtkPVClientServerCoreRendering;vtkPVServerManagerRendering;vtkPVVTKExtensionsRendering;vtkPVServerImplementationRendering
-- Group ParaViewQt modules: pqComponents;pqWidgets;pqCore;pqApplicationComponents
-- Backend OpenGL2 modules: vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2;vtkIOExportOpenGL2;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2;vtkRenderingOpenVR;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2;vtkRenderingOpenGL2;vtkRenderingLICOpenGL2;vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2;vtkImagingOpenGL2
-- Enabling modules for OpenGL2.
-- Checking whether header cstdio is available
-- Checking whether header cstdio is available - yes
-- Checking for Large File Support
-- Checking for Large File Support - yes
-- Checking whether C++ compiler has 'long long'
-- Checking whether C++ compiler has 'long long' - yes
-- Checking whether C++ compiler has '__int64'
-- Checking whether C++ compiler has '__int64' - no
-- Checking whether wstring is available
-- Checking whether wstring is available - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler has ptrdiff_t in stddef.h
-- Checking whether C compiler has ptrdiff_t in stddef.h - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler has ssize_t in unistd.h
-- Checking whether C compiler has ssize_t in unistd.h - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler has clock_gettime
-- Checking whether C compiler has clock_gettime - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has setenv
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has setenv - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has unsetenv
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has unsetenv - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has environ in stdlib.h
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has environ in stdlib.h - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimes - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimensat
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimensat - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtim member
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtim member - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtimespec member
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtimespec member - no
-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, ifaddrs.h
-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, ifaddrs.h - found
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has rlimit64
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has rlimit64 - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has atol
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has atol - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has atoll
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has atoll - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has _atoi64
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has _atoi64 - no
-- Looking for C++ include execinfo.h
-- Looking for C++ include execinfo.h - found
-- Checking whether backtrace works with this C++ compiler
-- Checking whether backtrace works with this C++ compiler - yes
-- Looking for C++ include dlfcn.h
-- Looking for C++ include dlfcn.h - found
-- Checking whether dladdr works with this C++ compiler
-- Checking whether dladdr works with this C++ compiler - yes
-- Looking for C++ include cxxabi.h
-- Looking for C++ include cxxabi.h - found
-- Checking whether cxxabi works with this C++ compiler
-- Checking whether cxxabi works with this C++ compiler - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has getloadavg
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has getloadavg - yes
-- Checking whether <ext/stdio_filebuf.h> is available
-- Checking whether <ext/stdio_filebuf.h> is available - yes
-- Checking for builtin __sync_add_and_fetch
-- Checking for builtin __sync_add_and_fetch -- success
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Test VTK_HAS_STD_ISNAN
-- Performing Test VTK_HAS_STD_ISNAN - Success
-- Performing Test VTK_HAS_STD_ISINF
-- Performing Test VTK_HAS_STD_ISINF - Success
-- Performing Test VTK_HAS_STD_ISFINITE
-- Performing Test VTK_HAS_STD_ISFINITE - Success
-- Looking for isnan
-- Looking for isnan - found
-- Looking for isinf
-- Looking for isinf - found
-- Looking for isfinite
-- Looking for isfinite - found
-- Looking for finite
-- Looking for finite - found
-- Looking for fenv.h
-- Looking for fenv.h - found
-- Looking for feenableexcept
-- Looking for feenableexcept - found
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Success
-- Looking for getsockname in socket
-- Looking for getsockname in socket - not found
-- Checking for getsockname with socklen_t
-- Checking for getsockname with socklen_t -- 1
-- Looking for SO_REUSEADDR
-- Looking for SO_REUSEADDR - found
-- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically
-- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_WERROR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_WERROR - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_pedantic
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_pedantic - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wall
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wall - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wextra
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wextra - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wundef
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wundef - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcastalign
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcastalign - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcharsubscripts
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcharsubscripts - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnonvirtualdtor
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnonvirtualdtor - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wunusedlocaltypedefs
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wunusedlocaltypedefs - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wpointerarith
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wpointerarith - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wwritestrings
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wwritestrings - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wformatsecurity
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wformatsecurity - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshorten64to32
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshorten64to32 - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wlogicalop
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wlogicalop - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wenumconversion
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wenumconversion - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcpp11extensions
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcpp11extensions - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wdoublepromotion
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wdoublepromotion - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnopsabi
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnopsabi - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnovariadicmacros
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnovariadicmacros - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnolonglong
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnolonglong - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnochecknew
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnochecknew - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnocommon
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnocommon - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fstrictaliasing
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fstrictaliasing - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd981
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd981 - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd2304
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd2304 - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_STRICTANSI
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_STRICTANSI - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Qunusedarguments
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Qunusedarguments - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_ansi
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_ansi - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP - Success
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so  
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
CMake Error at VTK/CMake/vtkQt.cmake:6 (message):
  Expected value for VTK_QT_VERSION is '5'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  VTK/GUISupport/Qt/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/bjd/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1812/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.6.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to upgrade to [Qt5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt5-intro.html). As indicated in reply to someone with a [similar error](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/203623-error-makeparaview-vtk_qt_version-5-of1806.html) .

To upgarde to Qt5 see this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062046/how-to-update-qt-from-5-5-1-to-5-9-5-on-ubuntu-16-04). ParaView was able to configure after this upgrade.